# How to get file info(name & size) after select file from input type file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.this_add').click(function(){
 
 $('.add_upload').append('<input type="file" name="image[]" class="this_upload">');
 var a = document.getElementById('abc');
 $('input[type="file"]:last').click();
 //$('input[type="file" name="image[]"]:last').remove();
 
});
$('.this_upload').change(function() {
  alert(Math.round(this.files[0].size / 1023.274693583273) +'kb|'+ this.files[0].name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
   <body>
      <button class="this_add">add</button>
      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="image[]" class="this_upload"/>
         <input type="file" name="image[]" class="this_upload"/>
         <input type="file" name="image[]" class="this_upload"/>
         <div class="add_upload"
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

When the `Add` button is clicked then it will generate a new input type file, but i can't get the file info after selecting a file from it. But it works if i selecting a file from the others input type file?

Comment: Your assignment of the `.change` handler doesn't extend into the future; it's only applied to the `<input>`s that exist at the time it runs. Try `$(document).on("change", ".this_upload", ...);`

Comment: @ChrisG thank you sir it work